# Select_tag doesn't get data from json response

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax, ruby-on-rails-4, coffeescript

### Problem

Please read edit, it's little cleaner.

select_tag using *Select2* not getting/sending ajax requests.

I'm trying to get data for my `select_tag` using ajax because there's a lot of rows in table.

```
<h3> Ajax send requests but I have Client.all </h3>
<%= invoice_form.collection_select :client_id, Client.all, :id, :name %>

<h3> Ajax not working </h3>
<input id="invoice_seller_id" />
```

These tags are used with [Select2](https://select2.github.io/) library to replace select boxes.

This is how it look in browser:
[image]

First `input` generated from `<%= invoice_form.collection_select :client_id, Client.all, :id, :name %>` send correct *json* requests and even get correct response.

[image]

But there is info that not results found.

In second approach browser doesn't even send ajax request.

## Code

invoices/_form.html.erb

```
<h3> Ajax send requests but I have Client.all </h3>
<%= invoice_form.collection_select :client_id, Client.all, :id, :name %>

<h3> Ajax not working </h3>
<input id="invoice_seller_id" />
```

invoice.js.coffee

```
jQuery ->
  $('#invoice_client_id').select2
    theme: 'bootstrap'
    ajax:
      url: '/clients.json'
      dataType: 'json'
      results: (data, page) ->
        { results: $.map(data, (client, i) ->
          {
            id: client.id
            text: client.name
          }
        ) }

    $('#invoice_seller_id').select2
      theme: 'bootstrap'
      ajax:
        url: '/clients.json'
        dataType: 'json'
        results: (data, page) ->
          { results: $.map(data, (client, i) ->
            {
              id: client.id
              text: client.name
            }
          ) }
```

## Question

Why in first *input* results are not inserted into *select_tag*. Why second input doesn;t send any requests?

I was trying recreate this: [Using Select2 with Ruby on Rails](https://teamtreehouse.com/library/using-select2-with-ruby-on-rails)

## Edit 1

I changed these two inpu fields just for one.

```
  <h3> Ajax not working </h3>
  <%= invoice_form.collection_select :seller_id, [], :id, :name %>
```

It's now sending ajax requests and get correct response but don't insert data to select options and still shows *No results found*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Select2` only works for `select` input tag. In second option you are just applying `select2` on input which is not `select` tag that's why it's not working.

Now why Result is not showing in select2.

Please be noted that `select2` expects the response in the form of

`[{id: 1,text: 'Option1'},{id: 2,text: 'Option2'}]` 
If the response is not like the above format then you need to processResults at client side. You are trying to do it but it appears you are choosing wrong option.
You need to define `processResult` so here is the script to do it.
You can find more details [Select2 Ajax FAQ](https://select2.github.io/options.html#ajax)

```
jQuery ->
  $('#invoice_client_id').select2
    theme: 'bootstrap'
    ajax:
      url: '/clients.json'
      dataType: 'json'
      processResults: (data) -> 
        return {
        results: $.map(data, (client, i) ->
          {
            id: client.id
            text: client.name
          }
       )}
```

I hope this works.

P.S Please be noted that when you are using remote option of select2 it's expected that you will filter the results on server side so select2 will display all of the returned results.